# Decode High Level Python to easier code

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a coding which I want to decode into simple programming such as simple nested 'for' loop or such. I know it might be a stupid question for high level programmers, but I am at very basic level of programming. So, please any help would be appreciated.

```
anything = {v: k for k, v in dic.items()} #Assume that 'dic' has already defined.
```

Can anyone help me to figure out how can I read this one of code, and decode it into simple nested loop? **Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most unrolled form would be

```
anything = dict()
for k in dic: # for each key in dic
    v = dic[k]
    anything[v] = k
```

basically this takes the dictionary `dic` and reverses the keys and values so that

```
{ 1: 2, 3: 4}
```

would become

```
{ 2:1, 4:3}
```

Answer (score 5):

The syntax `anything = {v: k for k, v in dic.items()}` is equivalent to:

```
anything = {}
for k, v in dic.items():
    anything[v] = k
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing that is difficult to understand if you are both beginning programming and beginning with Python is the declaration of variables in the for loop.

As a first concept, consider a list

```
mylist = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
```

If you wish to iterate through that list, you may do so by:

```
for item in mylist:
    print item
```

Python makes it very easy, as with other languages you may have to iterate through an index (think for i=0; i<10, i++) and then find the specific item you are looking for (think print mylist[i]).

What the above is doing is slightly more complicated because it iterates through a dictionary. Dictionaries items are represted as the following `mydict = {this: that, this1: that1, this3: that3}`

Dictionaries are used like this`mydict[this]` which would return `that`

Combining these two concepts is how you would arrive at the above answer.